# Evaluating pytorch models: `with torch.no_grad` vs `model.eval()`

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

When I want to evaluate the performance of my model on the validation set, is it preferred to use `with torch.no_grad:` or `model.eval()`?

Comment: Similar discussion here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/model-eval-vs-with-torch-no-grad/19615/2

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### TL;DR:

[Use *both*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19160#issuecomment-482188706). They do different things, and have different scopes.

- `with torch.no_grad` - disables tracking of gradients in `autograd`.
- `model.eval()` changes the `forward()` behaviour of the module it is called upon
- eg, it disables dropout and has batch norm use the entire population statistics

---

#### `with torch.no_grad`

The [`torch.autograd.no_grad` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.no_grad)  says:

> Context-manager that disabled [sic] gradient calculation.

> Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, when you are sure that you will not call `Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory consumption for computations that would otherwise have `requires_grad=True`. In this mode, the result of every computation will have `requires_grad=False`, even when the inputs have `requires_grad=True`.

#### `model.eval()`

The [`nn.Module.eval` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) says:

> Sets the module in evaluation mode.

> This has any effect only on certain modules. See documentations of particular modules for details of their behaviors in training/evaluation mode, if they are affected, e.g. `Dropout`, `BatchNorm`, etc.

---

[The creator of pytorch said the documentation should be updated to suggest the usage of both](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19160#issuecomment-482188706), and I raised the [pull request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/46173).

Answer (score 6):

`with torch.no_grad:` disables computation of gradients for the **backward** pass. Since these calculations are unnecessary during inference, and add non-trivial computational overhead, it is essessential to use this context if evaluating the model's speed. It will not however affect results.

`model.eval()` ensures [certain modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534762/which-pytorch-modules-are-affected-by-model-eval-and-model-train) which behave differently in training vs inference (e.g. Dropout and BatchNorm) are defined appropriately during the **forward** pass in inference. As such, if your model contains such modules it is essential to enable this.

For the reasons above it is good practice to use both during inference.

Answer (score 5):

If you're reading this post because you've been encountering `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory`, then `with torch.no grad():` will likely to help save the memory. Using only `model.eval()` is unlikely to help with the OOM error.

The reason for this is that `torch.no grad()` disables autograd completely (you can no longer backpropagate), reducing memory consumption and speeding up computations.

However, you will still be able to call the gardients when using `model.eval()`. Personally, I find this design decision intriguing. So, what is the purpose of `.eval()`? It seems its main functionality is to deactivate the Dropout during the evaluation time.

To summarize, if you use `torch.no grad()`, no intermediate tensors are saved, and you can possibly increase the batch size in your inference.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the link with the memory error, this is exactly what I was looking for!