# Which PyTorch modules are affected by model.eval() and model.train()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization, dropout

The `model.eval()` method modifies certain modules (layers) which are required to behave differently during training and inference. Some examples are listed in [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval):

> This has [an] effect only on certain modules. See documentations of particular modules for details of their behaviors in training/evaluation mode, if they are affected, e.g. `Dropout`, `BatchNorm`, etc.

Is there an exhaustive list of which modules are affected?

Comment: I think... that's about that? I dont recall any other standard layer that changes its behaviour, but maybe I'm wrong and I  would be promptly corrected if the list existed :)) I take into account all layers that inherits from `BatchNorm` of course

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to info provided by [@iacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66544446/10886420):

| Base class | Module | Criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`RNNBase`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNNBase.html#torch.nn.RNNBase) | RNN LSTM GRU | `dropout > 0` (default: `0`) |
| Transformer layers | Transformer TransformerEncoder TransformerDecoder | `dropout > 0` (`Transformer` default: `0.1`) |
| Lazy variants | LazyBatchNorm **currently nightly** [merged PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/51548) | `track_running_stats=True` |

Comment: GroupNorm and LayerNorm do not track running stats and are not affected by model.eval().

Answer (score 7):

Searching [**site:**https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn. **"**during evaluation**"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fpytorch.org%2Fdocs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Ftorch.nn.+%22during%20evaluation%22) on google, it would appear the following modules are affected:

| Base class | Modules | Criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`_InstanceNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/instancenorm.html) | InstanceNorm1d InstanceNorm2d InstanceNorm3d | `track_running_stats=True` |
| [`_BatchNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html) | BatchNorm1d BatchNorm2d BatchNorm3d SyncBatchNorm |  |
| [`_DropoutNd`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/dropout.html) | Dropout Dropout2d Dropout3d AlphaDropout FeatureAlphaDropout |  |